# npm 'module not found', but everything seems to be set up correct

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

it seems my **node_modules folder is being ignored**. When I add new modules via 'npm install' the get installed correctly, but trying to import them results in a 'module not found' error. I can even **delete** the whole '**node_modules**' folder and the **app is still working**.

I've installed some modules globally but I can't import them as well. It worked fine a couple a weeks ago, but now every change I do to the folder is being ignored...

```
npm: 5.5.1
node: 6.11.3
npm prefix: path/to/my/project
npm prefix -g: /usr/local
npm list --depth=0: returns my installed modules
npm install: installs the modules correctly into the 'node_modules' folder
```

Other technology used: React, JSX, Babel

I"m importing via `import _ from 'lodash';`

Any idea what's going on? I tried to solve the problem for two days now...

**Examples**:

```
npm install react-pdf --save
```

installs correctly into the node_modules folder and shows up under 'npm list --depth=0' but trying to import it results in:

```
Failed to compile.

Error in ./src/components/ProductSearch.js
Module not found: 'react-pdf' in /node/src/components

 @ ./src/components/ProductSearch.js 32:16-36
```

Updating react to 16.0.0 works well, I end up with 16.0.0 in my 'node_modules' folder but the app is still using 15.3.2

Comment: Can you give a minimal example where you're having a problem so we can try and reproduce it?

Comment: updated question

Comment: If you can explain what you did to fix this more specifically it's worth adding a self-answer. If not, then it's probably best to delete this to avoid confusing people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a Docker issue. The image did't update correctly. It worked when using 'npm start'.

I needed to re-build the docker image...

Answer (score 0):

If there in project is used webpack.config.js, might `moduleDirectories: ['node_modules']` could help with that:

```
resolve: {
  root: path.resolve('./src'),
  extensions: ['', '.js'],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules']
}
```